# RAID1 speed limit

Tags: usb, raid

I've got a RAID1 with two SATA drives in SATA-USB-Adaptors. One is USB 3.0, one is USB 2.0. Does the USB 2.0 limit the write speed of that array?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as soon as you have filled up the systems buffers, your program will start to wait for the writes to complete to the slower disc.

If that were not the case, the RAID software would essentially have to dynamically degrade the array and then sync in the background.

In your case (!) I would upgrade the USB 2.0 external drive to a USB 3.0 enclosure.